# How to use Array.reduce with Typescript properly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently i'm using this method like that:

```
[].reduce<GenericType>(
            (acc, { value, status, time }) => {
                if (time) {
                    return {
                        ...acc,
                        bestValue: value,
                        status: status.toString(),
                        isOld: true,
                        time
                    };
                }
                return {
                    bestValue: null,
                    status: '',
                    isOld: false
                };
            },
            {
                bestValue: null,
                status: '',
                isOld: false
            }
        );
```

But as for me It's weird. If I go with {} as default value I'll get TS error.
I'll be thankful for any tips.

Comment: *"I'll be thankful for any tips."* My tip: Use a simple loop and bypass all the unnecessary complexity. :-) `reduce` is useful if you're doing functional programming with predefnied, reusable reducer functions. Otherwise, it's just an overcomplicated loop that's easy to get wrong and easy to misunderstand.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I'm using reduce in TS:

```js
interface Value {
  bestValue: unknown;
  status: string;
  isOld: boolean;
  time: string;
}

const initialValue: Value = {
  bestValue: null,
  status: '',
  isOld: false,
  time: ''
};

interface Item {
  value: number;
  status: string;
  time: string;
}

const array: Item[] = [
  {
    value: 1,
    status: 'active',
    time: '00:00'
  }
];

const result = array.reduce(
  (acc, { value, status, time }) =>
    time
      ? {
        ...acc,
        bestValue: value,
        status: status.toString(),
        isOld: true,
        time
      }
      : {
        bestValue: null,
        status: '',
        isOld: false,
        time: '' // You forgot to define all required properties
      },
  initialValue
);
```

I think it is good practice to define all properties as required in your reduced object.
So, instead of null it is better to use initial value, in this case every iteration will return same interface